# what is the best way to convert a Qt object(QgraphicsItem) into C++ class object

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, dynamic-cast

I am trying to convert a Qt object into a C++ class object in a loop like this

```
std::vector<PBWMPlugDeviceGraphicsItem*> deviceItms;

for(int i=0; i<fScene->items().size(); i++)
    deviceItms.push_back(dynamic_cast<PBWMPlugDeviceGraphicsItem*>(fScene->items().at(i)));
```

Where `PBWMPlugDeviceGraphicsItem` is a C++ class. It seems that, when total no. of items is larger than a certain threshold (e.g. `fScene->items().size() >900`), it takes a considerable amount of time to convert these objects and because of that I can see operation on my `QGraphicsScene` to be very slow. I read that `dynamic_cast` has serious performace issues.

Is there any other great/fast way to achieve the same result?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't convert any "objects" at all, you just convert pointers. Please also define "very slow", is that a few seconds or microseconds? BTW: You might end up with a few null pointers in there, and one obvious performance impact is the index validation in `vector::at()`.

Comment: What does `fScene->items()` return?

Comment: Very good point by Mr. C64. Repeatedly retrieving and then discarding a vector isn't such a good idea!

Comment: fScene->Items() returns the list of all items on the QgraphicsScene and it takes like few seconds (2-5) seconds .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is calling `QList::at`, which returns reference to list item, which causes `QList` to do copy-on-write detach.

Minimal solution is to call `QList::value` to get the pointer, instead of `at`.

Other solution is to fetch the list once, as explained in other answers. This way detach will only happen once even if you use `at`.

You could also force use of const version of `at` by cast or temp variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
for (auto p: fScene->items())
    deviceItms.push_back(dynamic_cast<PBWMPlugDeviceGraphicsItem*>(p));
```

Two important differences:

- It only calls `fScene->items()` once. Unless that function returns by (const) reference, retrieving and discarding a container for each iteration is useless overhead, in particular if the content is not supposed to change between iterations.
- Instead of using an index and validating that index in `at()`, it uses C++11 for loops with an automatically typed variable. The `at()` is only useful if you have doubts whether an index is valid (e.g. when it was input from the user), but if you can't program a simple loop, you really have more important issues.

I didn't take the third optimization of using `vector::reserve()` to pre-allocate memory. If you really only have a few objects (yes, 900 is few), then it's probably hardly noticeable. Still, do some research on that, as it's a tool that you should know about.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<fScene->items().size(); i++)
>   deviceItms.push_back(dynamic_cast<PBWMPlugDeviceGraphicsItem*>(fScene->items().at(i)));
> ```

Based on a comment reply, it seems `fScene->items()` returns something like `QList<QGraphicsItem *>`.

As your code is written, instances of this QList are created and discarded at every loop iteration. So, as first optimization, I'd try getting that list *outside* the loop *once*, and then processing that same instance inside the loop, avoiding wasting creation/destruction of the list at each loop iteration.

If you can use C++11, I agree with @Ulrich's suggestion of using a range-based for loop: this will make the code both *simpler* and *faster*.

---

**EDIT**

In a comment here you wrote that you can't use C++11, so you can't enjoy range-based for loops.
Then, an alternative might be:

```
// Get the collection of items once, outside the loop
QList<QGraphicsItem *> items = fScene->items();

// For each graphics item in the collection...
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    deviceItems.push_back(dynamic_cast<PBWMPlugDeviceGraphicsItem*>(items.at(i)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !. i will try to implement and let you know about the performace!

Answer (score 0):

ThankYou all!
your suggestion are very useful. I implemented in following way(as i can't use C++11)

```
        QList<QGraphicsItem*> temp= fScene->items();
    for(int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++)
        deviceItms.push_back(dynamic_cast<PBWMPlugDeviceGraphicsItem*>(temp[i]));
```

and it is working absolutely fine.

Thankyou very much for the useful tips! 
I really learned somethign new.